# Android lock screen / media controls on the lock screen

Tags: android, audio, lockscreen, keyguard

i have a few questions, to which i haven't found answers till now, despite searching the forum and much of googling.

On thing first, i'm developing for android gingerbread, so newer/not all functions are available.

1. Is it somehow possible to force the lock screen to redraw/update?
2. Can i somehow manipulate the built-in media controls on the lock screen, which appear when i'm playing music, through a function/an intent or something? For example that the media controls show the pause state (only the play button is shown) instead of showing the play state (3 buttons are shown). Because i'm developing for gingerbread, i cannot use the RemoteControlClient.
3. Can i somehow dynamically disable/unregister the appearance of the media controls on the lock screen through code? The media controls on the lock screen shall not be shown despite playing music.

---

EDIT

Upon the answer of [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), for the second and third question, i use a cyanogen mod rom, so the media controls are comming from cyanogen.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it somehow possible to force the lock screen to redraw/update?

Not really.

> Can i somehow manipulate the built-in media controls on the lock screen
>   Can i somehow dynamically disable/unregister the appearance of the media controls on the lock screen through code?

There are no "built-in media controls on the lock screen" in Android 2.3. Certain devices from certain device manufacturers may have extended their lockscreens support media controls, in which case you would have to ask your questions of those device manufacturers.

Comment: I already thought so, that the lock screen can't be updated.

I'm using a cyanogen mod rom, so maybe someone knows if i or how i can modify the media controls on the lock screen there?